# Solve the following integral: $ \int \frac{x^2}{x^2+x-2} dx $

Tags: integration, polynomials, rational-functions

Solve the integral: $ \int \frac{x^2}{x^2+x-2} dx $

I was hoping that writing it in the form $ \int 1 - \frac{x-2}{x^2+x-2} dx $ would help but I'm still not getting anywhere.

In the example it was re-written as $ \int 1 - \frac{4}{3x+6} - \frac{1}{3x-3} dx $

but I am not sure how this was accomplished. Any ideas? I am more interested in the method than the answer.

Comment: Hint: use $x^2+x-2 = (x-1)(x+2)$ and make a [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^2+x-2 = (x-1)(x+2)$, we can use partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{x-2}{x^2+x-2} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x+2}.$$

Then $x-2 = A(x+2) + B(x-1)$.

Equating the coefficients of each power of $x$, we have that $1=A+B$, and $-2=2A-B$.

Solving for $A$ and $B$ decomposes our original rational expression into two simple fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can divide the numerator with the denominator and rewrite the integral in this way: $$\int q(x)+\int D(x)/R(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

when you get the $\int 1 - \frac{x-2}{x^2+x-2} dx$, you can use  $x^2+x-2 = (x-1)(x+2)$.
then it become
$$
\int 1 - \frac{x+2-4}{(x+2)(x-1)}dx
$$
which equal to 
$$
\int 1 - \frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{4}{(x+2)(x-1)}dx
$$
$$
\int 1 - \frac{1}{x-1}-4/3(\frac{1}{(x-1)}+\frac{1}{(x+2)})dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

While partial fraction expansion is certainly the natural choice, here is a slightly different approach that continues from the OP's attempt.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{x^2+x-2}&=1-\frac{x-2}{x^2+x-2}\\\\
&=1-\frac12 \frac{2x-4}{x^2+x-2}\\\\
&=1-\frac12 \frac{2x+1-5}{x^2+x-2}\\\\
&1-\frac12 \frac{2x+1}{x^2+x-2}+ \frac{5/2}{x^2+x-2}\\\\
&=1-\frac12 \frac{2x+1}{x^2+x-2}+ \frac{5/2}{(x+1/2)^2-(3/2)^2}
\end{align}$$

Now, the first term is trivial to integrate.  The second term is a perfect differential since the numerator is the derivative of the denominator.  And the last term is set up for a hyperbolic trigonometric substitution.